Let's deal with the [if] tag, else it'll become a problem
The if tag exists, most notably on questions about the IF functionality in Microsoft Excel, but it has been used for all sorts of conditional and branching questions.
Is it worth keeping separate? Would it be better IF it were merged and synonymised with conditional-statements? Or perhaps removed outright?

I'm in favor of @JoepvanSteen's suggestion.

While most legit uses of if will be conditional statements, there will likely be a small but significant number of posters looking for tags to add, and if is a very common word.
I believe the better course is daleeking the tag rather than synonimizing it: EXTERMINATE! EXTERMINATE!

Looks like it's been removed now :)

Yea, I spammed the feed for a bit removing all of them.
